# Does Spring Webflow 2.x still support gradual conversion from Struts 1.x?

Tags: java, struts, enterprise, spring-webflow

I've been trying for a long time to move this large project I'm working on away from the now quite dated struts 1.x framework and on to something newer.

The main blocker has been that we aren't given enough time for a complete re-write.

I came across this article:
http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/28041/0/page/3

Which seems to suggest that web-flow would be a good/easy way to start getting out of struts actions.

Unfortunately when I downloaded the current 2.0.8 release of web-flow I found that all of the struts classes are no longer included.

Is there a separate project for the struts integration? Or has it just been flat out dropped?

All my searches seem to turn up information about older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers here, or on the spring forum, most likely due to lack of interest in struts 1.x (can't blame people for that).

For what it's worth, the classes aren't in the 2.x web-flow jar's nor in any other module I've been able to find for the 2.x spring framework, so basically the answer is no, out of the box, you've got to completely drop struts 1.x

We haven't investigated porting the integration classes to webflow 2.x ourselves yet, but it's an option we're considering

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this. According to Keith Donald [in this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?52222-Spring-Webflow-2-0-Problems-integrating-with-struts) it does NOT support integration with Struts 1.0 out of the box since version 2x.